# checking if a cookie is set then display logoff link using jquery cookie library

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am trying to clear a DNN cookie using the `cookie.js` library.
When the user clicks login they should login via the CMS. then the jquery needs to:

check if the cookie is set (if its set then hide the login link and display logoff)

Here is my attempt:

**HTML:**

```
<a id="dnn_dnnLOGIN_cmdLogin" href="Login">
    Login
</a>

||

<a id="dnn_dnnLOGIN_cmdLogin" href="Logoff">
    Logoff
</a>

<br />

<a id="see" href="#">
    see if cookie is set?
</a>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('#dnn_dnnLOGIN_cmdLogin').live('click', function() {
    var preval = $.cookie('DNN-COOKIE');
    if(preval != null) {
        $(this).hide();
    } else {
    var action = $(this).attr('href');
    var cookie_value = (action == 'Login') ? 1 : null;

    $.cookie('DNN-COOKIE', cookie_value);
    }
    return false;
});

// clicking on 'see' should bring up an alert box display the cookie value of 1 or 0
$('#see').live('click', function() {

    alert($.cookie('DNN-COOKIE'));

    return false;
});
```

I have added the library resource to this JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/whQaq/
I need to check if the cookie is set

**EDIT: here is an example which seems to be working but in DNN when i place the code in the skin file it doesnt work.** http://jsfiddle.net/whQaq/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would test the following:

```
$.cookie('DNN-COOKIE', null);
```

then retrieve:

```
var preval = $.cookie('DNN-COOKIE')
```

and assert that:

```
preval === null;
```

In any case, it's probably safer to use:

```
if(!preval) {
    $(this).hide();
}
```

UPDATE:

Could it be you need to set the cookie to your domain's root:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { path: '/' });
```

That might be the case if you're using subdomains.

Comment: Thanks i have created this, seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/whQaq/3/ but doesnt work in my skin

Comment: Ok, looks like passing null does delete a cookie, see docs: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: Could it be that you need to set the cookie path?